# How can i get last inserted record from mongodb with spring boot data?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to know about to get the last inserted record from mongodb with spring boot data ?
i didn't find any exact solution . is there any way to fetch the last inserted record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's not necessarily *last-inserted*, you can get the *latest* `ObjectID timestamp` per a query something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$sort: { createdOn: -1 }},
    {$group: { _id: "$itemId", 
        createdOn: {$first: "$createdOn"}
    }}
])
```